# Synology MSQL connection error

Tags: php, mysqli, synology

I tried to move a database from XAMPP to my Synology NAS.

Now I get this error:

> `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'qs'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /volume1/web/db.php on line 3`

In the Database i created a User:

```
Name: qs
password: test
host: %
privileges: all..
```

in php i use:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","qs","test","qs",3306);
```

localhost because the Synology is the localhost of the web-page. i also tried to change to:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("10.0.0.99","qs","test","qs",3306);
```

then it says:

> `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'qs'@'JF_SYN' (using password: YES) in /volume1/web/db.php on line 3`

"JF_SYN" is the name of my Synology

i also tried to set the host of the database user, to that specific IP, but that doesn't change anything.

Database connection is working with this user and the password, i tried with HeidSQL,MSYQL-Workbench and Oracle SQL Developer, all those tools can make a connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,  with my Synology NAS

Use MyAdmin and remove the “ANY” or “Anonymous” user accounts.
This should Fix your issue.